# Eliminar contenido de carrito de compra en javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
var libros = [];
 libros[0] = ["img/libro1.jpg", "Calcetines Rotos", 16.5];
 libros[1] = ["img/libro2.jpg", "Patria", 21.80];
 libros[2] = ["img/libro3.jpg", "Los ritos del agua", 20.00];
 libros[3] = ["img/libro4.jpg", "El extraño verano de Tom Harvey", 15.90];
 libros[4] = ["img/libro5.jpg", "La Habitacion en llamas", 16.00];
 libros[5] = ["img/libro6.jpg", "El secreto de Ile-De-Sein", 21.8];
 libros[6] = ["img/libro7.jpg", "Ocho días de Marzo", 15.90];
 libros[7] = ["img/libro8.jpg", "Cinco días de Octubre", 15.90];

var div = document.getElementById("contenedorlibro")
    , titulo = div.getElementsByTagName("h3")
    , img = div.getElementsByTagName("img")
    , precio = div.getElementsByTagName("p");

var salida = "";

function multiple(valor, multiplo) {
    resto = valor % multiplo;
    if (resto == 0) return true;
    else return false;
}

//Añadir div's con el contenido del producto segun la array de libros.

for (i = 0; i < libros.length; i++) {

    if (i == 0) {
        salida += "<div class='row'>";
    }

    else if (i != 0 && multiple(i, 4)) {
        salida += "</div>\n<div class='row'>";
    }

    salida += "<div class='col-md-3 producto col-xs-12 col-sm-6'> <img alt='Libro 1' src='" 
        + libros[i][0] + 
        " ' class='img-rounded' style='width:50%' ><h3 class='text-primary text-center'>" 
        + "<b>Título:</b> " + libros[i][1] + 
        "</h3><p class='precios'>" + "€" 
        + libros[i][2] + 
        "</p><button id='comprar" 
        + i + 
        "' onClick='add(this)' type='button' class='btn btn-primary active btn-default compra'> Comprar </button></div>";
}

    if (i != 0) {
        salida += "</div>";
    }

div.innerHTML = salida;

var row = ""
    ,preciosuma = 0
    ,ref
    ,des=0
    ,coniva=0
    ,total=0;


function add(boton) {
    var pos = boton.id.split("comprar")
        indice = pos[1]
        tablacompra = document.getElementById("tablacompra")
        numtr = tablacompra.getElementsByTagName("tr") 
        precio = 0;
    
    ref = numtr.length + 1;
    row += '<tr class="active carrito"><td>' 
        + ref + 
        ' </td><td>' 
        + libros[indice][1] + 
        ' </td><td> € ' 
        + libros[indice][2] + 
        ' <button type="button" onClick="quitarlibro()">Quitar</button>';
    
    document.getElementById(boton.id).setAttribute("disabled", "disabled"); //Deshabilita boton de comprar

    tablacompra.innerHTML = row;    
    precio = libros[indice][2];
    preciosuma = preciosuma + precio;
    
    //Llama a las siguientes funciones que aparecerán en la tabla de precios finales.

    descuento();
    iva();
    totalprecio();
    tablaprecios();
}

function totalprecio() {
    total = (preciosuma-des)+coniva;
}

function iva() {
    coniva = (preciosuma - des)*0.21;
}

function descuento() {
    
    if (ref >= 3 && ref<5) {
        des = preciosuma * 0.05;
    }
    
    if (ref >= 5 && ref<7){
        des = preciosuma * 0.075;
    }
    
    if (ref >= 7){
        des = preciosuma * 0.1;
    }

    return des;
}

function tablaprecios(){
    
    var tablaprecios = document.getElementById("tablaprecios"),
        columnas = tablaprecios.getElementsByTagName("td");

    columnas[1].innerHTML = preciosuma.toFixed(2) + " €";
    
    if (ref >= 3 && ref<5 ){
        columnas[3].innerHTML = des.toFixed(2) + " (-5%)";
    }

    if (ref >= 5 && ref<7){
        columnas[3].innerHTML = des.toFixed(2) + " (-7.5%)";
    }

    if (ref >= 7){
        columnas[3].innerHTML = des.toFixed(2) + " (-10%)";
    }

    columnas[5].innerHTML = coniva.toFixed(2) + " (21%)";
    columnas[7].innerHTML = total.toFixed(2) + " €";
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Comprar Libros Online</title>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h3>Compra online de libros</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="contenedorlibro">
            </div>            
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; margin-bottom: 30px;">
                    <h3>Carrito de Compras:</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row carritocompra">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <table class="table table-condensed">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Num</th>
                                <th>Producto</th>
                                <th colspan="2">Precio</th>
                            </tr>
                        <tbody id="tablacompra">
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <table id="tablaprecios" class="table table-condensed" style="margin-top: 30px;">
                            <tr>
                                <td>Total Compra:</td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="active">
                                <td>Descuento: </td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="active">
                                <td>IVA: (21%) </td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="success">
                                <td>Importe Total: </td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de carro de la compra por javascript y no consigo hacer la función de quitar un objeto añadido al carrito, le aplico un botón de "quitar" pero estoy perdido en qué función tengo que hacer para que quite el objeto y vuelva a habilitar su correspondiente botón de compra, muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Si puedes añadir el código nos facilitarías mucho la tarea.

Comment: perdona, creía que lo había añadido pero no entiendo muy bien porqué no aperece, ahora lo vuelvo a intentar, gracias Erlantz!

Comment: *Código añadido

Comment: Al ejecutar el código se muestra el error quitarlibro no está definido, falta que indique que has intentado en cuanto a esta función ya que es a lo que se refiere la pregunta.

Comment: Buenas ruben, la verdad es que ando perdido y no se qué función hacerle a esa parte, la he puesto porqué creo que tengo que tirar por ahí pero estoy en blanco..

Answer (score 1):

```js
var libros = [];
 libros[0] = ["img/libro1.jpg", "Calcetines Rotos", 16.5];
 libros[1] = ["img/libro2.jpg", "Patria", 21.80];
 libros[2] = ["img/libro3.jpg", "Los ritos del agua", 20.00];
 libros[3] = ["img/libro4.jpg", "El extraño verano de Tom Harvey", 15.90];
 libros[4] = ["img/libro5.jpg", "La Habitacion en llamas", 16.00];
 libros[5] = ["img/libro6.jpg", "El secreto de Ile-De-Sein", 21.8];
 libros[6] = ["img/libro7.jpg", "Ocho días de Marzo", 15.90];
 libros[7] = ["img/libro8.jpg", "Cinco días de Octubre", 15.90];

var div = document.getElementById("contenedorlibro")
    , titulo = div.getElementsByTagName("h3")
    , img = div.getElementsByTagName("img")
    , precio = div.getElementsByTagName("p");

var salida = "";

function multiple(valor, multiplo) {
    resto = valor % multiplo;
    if (resto == 0) return true;
    else return false;
}

//Añadir div's con el contenido del producto segun la array de libros.

for (i = 0; i < libros.length; i++) {

    if (i == 0) {
        salida += "<div class='row'>";
    }

    else if (i != 0 && multiple(i, 4)) {
        salida += "</div>\n<div class='row'>";
    }

    salida += "<div class='col-md-3 producto col-xs-12 col-sm-6'> <img alt='Libro 1' src='" 
        + libros[i][0] + 
        " ' class='img-rounded' style='width:50%' ><h3 class='text-primary text-center'>" 
        + "<b>Título:</b> " + libros[i][1] + 
        "</h3><p class='precios'>" + "€" 
        + libros[i][2] + 
        "</p><button id='comprar" 
        + i + 
        "' onClick='add(this)' type='button' class='btn btn-primary active btn-default compra'> Comprar </button></div>";
}

    if (i != 0) {
        salida += "</div>";
    }

div.innerHTML = salida;

var row = ""
    ,preciosuma = 0
    ,ref
    ,des=0
    ,coniva=0
    ,total=0;


function add(boton) {
    var pos = boton.id.split("comprar")
        indice = pos[1]
        tablacompra = document.getElementById("tablacompra")
        numtr = tablacompra.getElementsByTagName("tr") 
        precio = 0;
    
    ref = numtr.length + 1;
    id = "'p"+ref+"'";
    row += '<tr id="'+id+'" class="active carrito" onClick="quitarlibro('+id+')"><td>' 
        + ref + 
        ' </td><td>' 
        + libros[indice][1] + 
        ' </td><td> € ' 
        + libros[indice][2] + 
        ' <button type="button">Quitar</button>';
    
    document.getElementById(boton.id).setAttribute("disabled", "disabled"); //Deshabilita boton de comprar

    tablacompra.innerHTML = row;    
    precio = libros[indice][2];
    preciosuma = preciosuma + precio;
    
    //Llama a las siguientes funciones que aparecerán en la tabla de precios finales.

    descuento();
    iva();
    totalprecio();
    tablaprecios();
}

function totalprecio() {
    total = (preciosuma-des)+coniva;
}

function iva() {
    coniva = (preciosuma - des)*0.21;
}

function descuento() {
    
    if (ref >= 3 && ref<5) {
        des = preciosuma * 0.05;
    }
    
    if (ref >= 5 && ref<7){
        des = preciosuma * 0.075;
    }
    
    if (ref >= 7){
        des = preciosuma * 0.1;
    }

    return des;
}

function tablaprecios(){
    
    var tablaprecios = document.getElementById("tablaprecios"),
        columnas = tablaprecios.getElementsByTagName("td");

    columnas[1].innerHTML = preciosuma.toFixed(2) + " €";
    
    if (ref >= 3 && ref<5 ){
        columnas[3].innerHTML = des.toFixed(2) + " (-5%)";
    }

    if (ref >= 5 && ref<7){
        columnas[3].innerHTML = des.toFixed(2) + " (-7.5%)";
    }

    if (ref >= 7){
        columnas[3].innerHTML = des.toFixed(2) + " (-10%)";
    }

    columnas[5].innerHTML = coniva.toFixed(2) + " (21%)";
    columnas[7].innerHTML = total.toFixed(2) + " €";
    
}

function quitarlibro(index){
alert("Eliminando");
 var parent = document.getElementById("'"+index+"'").parentNode;
 parent.removeChild(document.getElementById("'"+index+"'"));
 alert("Eliminado");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Comprar Libros Online</title>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h3>Compra online de libros</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="contenedorlibro">
            </div>            
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; margin-bottom: 30px;">
                    <h3>Carrito de Compras:</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row carritocompra">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <table class="table table-condensed" id="carrito">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Num</th>
                                <th>Producto</th>
                                <th colspan="2">Precio</th>
                            </tr>
                        <tbody id="tablacompra">
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <table id="tablaprecios" class="table table-condensed" style="margin-top: 30px;">
                            <tr>
                                <td>Total Compra:</td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="active">
                                <td>Descuento: </td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="active">
                                <td>IVA: (21%) </td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="success">
                                <td>Importe Total: </td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

He adjuntado el nuevo código para que lo puedas probar.

Entiendo que tu problema era eliminar contenido del carrito de compra y por tanto eso es lo que resolví, y lo otro deberás ir solucionándolo tú.

En esencia cuando insertas un nuevo `<tr>` se le indica un nuevo `id` el cual es "p" + id del "NUM". Por tanto al eliminar `<tr>` envía el `onclick` con su propio `id`, y le indica que debe eliminar ese `id`. Los problemas que ahora hay son los siguientes, para que se te haga mas sencillo:

1.- `ref` debe redefinirse para que indique la verdadera cantidad de nodos que hay.

2.- Deben ejecutarse nuevamente `Total Compra`, `Descuento`, `IVA` e `Importe Total`.

3.- Solucionar al colocar `add` ya que tiene un conteo separado.

Espero que esto te ayude y que tengas éxito en tu proyecto!

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: @JordiR Me alegro que te haya podido ayudar :D